# How to loop and alert the key and value is stored in array jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have store value into my array

Example:

```
var arr = new Array();
var t = 'orrange';
var r = '1';

arr.push({r:t});
```

And I tried to loop the array and get the result

```
$.each( arr, function( key, value ) {
alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

it show the result is "0,object:object"

If there any mistake, please correct me.
Thanks.

Comment: There's no mistake, that's how you loop through the array.

Comment: This question misses what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr` is array of objects, `key` gives index of array (0,1,2, etc) and `value` is the object itself, so `value.r` gives `orrange`, and `r` gives `1`

```
var arr = [];
var t = 'orrange';
var r = '1';

arr.push({r:t});
$.each( arr, function( key, value ) {
    //key in here is index of your arr Array
    alert( key + ": " + value.r ); //gives 0: orrange
});
```

when you do: `{r:t}` its `{key:value}` pair, so `1` is the **key** and `orrange` is its **value**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.each( arr, function( key, value ) {

   console.log(value.r); // orrange

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log instead of alert and check your browser console for the variables that you log. It will give you an idea of what is going wrong.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29QQV/

Used `console.log(value);`

Answer (score 0):

Pushing to the array is wrong. Try

```
arr.push(t,r);
```

instead of

```
arr.push({r:t});
```